# Extracting a particular value from a JSON file

Tags: json, awk, sed, jq

From the JSON file below I want to extract `X Time` and `Y Time`. What is the easiest way to do this?

```
{
    "Timestamp": "Mon Mar 16 21:37:22 EDT 2015",
    "Event": "Reporting  Time",
    "Message": "load for http://xxx.xx.xx.xx:1xxxx/operations&proxy=www.mywebsite.co.nz&send=https://xxx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx took (X Time: 306 ms, Y Time: 1923 ms)StatusCode: Unknown<br>Cookies: nzh_weatherlocation=12; dax_ppv=11|NZH:home|NZH:home|NZH:home|9|undefined; Safari/537.36<br>CPUs: 2<br>Language: en-GB",

}
```

Comment: Your json string is not valid. Can you validate this? http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/  Also, What key/value are you trying to extract? You want to do this in JavaScript?

Comment: @duyn9uyen, It is a valid JSON if you don't take into consideration the \t and \r\n. And considering the question has awk as tag, I don't think he's working with JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use grep.

```
$ grep -o '[YX]\s*Time:\s*[^,)]*' file
X Time: 306 ms
Y Time: 1923 ms
```

- `[YX]` will match either `X` or `Y`
- `\s*` matches zero or more space characters.
- `Time:\s*` Matches the string `Time` plus the following zero or more spaces.
- `[^,)]*` Negated character class which matches any character but not of comma or `)`, zero or more times.

Comment: Can you please explain this regular expression?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jq solution using **capture**:

```
  .Message
| capture("X Time: (?<X Time>[^,]+), Y Time: (?<Y Time>[^)]+)")
```

If this filter is in `filter.jq` and input data is in `input.json`

```
jq -M -f filter.jq input.json
```

will produce

```
{
  "X Time": "306 ms",
  "Y Time": "1923 ms"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, i recomend to your Gson or Jackson Libraries (are used to serialize/deserialize) json objects easier.

But, if i were you i make it manually of this way:

JsonObject MyJson= new JsonObject(yourstring);

1.- To obtain the X Time or Y Time:

```
String FullMessage=MyJson.getString("message");

int XPosition=FullMessage.indexOf("X Time:");
int YPosition=FullMessage.indexOf("Y Time:");
int EndYPosition=FullMessage.indexOf("ms)");

String XTime=FullMessage.substring(XPosition,Yposition);
String YTime=FullMessage.subString(Yposition,EndYPosition);
```

/*
of that way you could obtain x and y data, i havent tested it, but the main idea i write.
*/

2.-And to Write the url is easy, just make it:

```
MyObject.putString("url","www.mywebsite.co.nz"); //and thats all
```

But i recommend to use and Serializer/deserializer library, its easier and better.

Regards.